# Not able to run sample chromecast application from github from chrome browser

Tags: chromecast

I am new to chromecast , I am trying to run the sample googlecast/CastHelloText-chrome , I whitelisted my device as well , but still not able to run any sample sender-receiver chroemcast app.

Comment: If you want to get help, you need to be a lot more specific than "it is not working" type statements; show your code, show the errors, show the logs and provide enough content for someone else to be able to look at and provide help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to chromecast also but have a working app and extension in github, https://github.com/pswtkw/Chromecast-Starter_App.git if it helps you out.  Its the sample provided by Google I changed a few things and got it working, for a starting point.

I changed all the videos to the bunny one, some didn't load and I didn't want to mess with them, just fyi.

Comment: Thanx for reply.As the link u mentioned is only the sender app. My only sender app is working properly but when i write custom receiver application its not working. I hosted the receiver app at google drive and got the application Id but still not able to run sample receiver application https://github.com/googlecast/cast-custom-receiver.